# How to stop captive-long in Elementary OS Freya?

Tags: elementary-os

I have a small problem with Elementary OS 0.3 (Freya). Whenever I connect to the network, an application `captive-login` used to run. I removed that application by deleting the executable. Now whenever I connect to the network, google chrome opens 4 tabs - all going to start.elementaryos.org .

How can I prevent google chrome from opening these tabs, or remove captive-login in a way that won't cause this?

Comment: Workaround for `start.elementaryos.org`: add an entry like `127.0.0.99 start.elementaryos.org` to your `/etc/hosts` file - then no process will easily access that page.  You could, of course, also set your start/home page in your web browser and/or its system configuration file(s) and/or your desktop manager settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop "captive-login" with the following steps:

1. First delete `sudo rm /usr/bin/captive-login` or make backup.
2. Create a new captive login executable: `sudo nano /usr/bin/captive-login`
3. Write the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exit 0
   ```
4. Permissions for the new `captive-login` executable: `chmod 777 /usr/bin/captive-login`

These steps work for me, I don't know if this bug is already solved.

Comment: Alternatively, `sudo cp -p /bin/true /usr/bin/captive-login` to make it appear as if the file is there.  Then you need to disable updating that package (blacklist in your package manager?), or repeat the procedure after each update that restores the file.

Comment: Wow. This actually helped. Thanks a lot. I'd been struggling with this issue for way too long. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the popup by crippling the executable is discouraged when there's a package manager. You don't know what else will break and updates may eventually reintroduce the file when you least expect it.

Instead you should find the package providing `captive-login` and examine what other files it provides, usually with Debian derived systems you'll find that large software suites are split into several smaller packages.

You can find which package `captive-login` belongs to with

```
dpkg -S $(which captive-login)
```

You should then list the other files it contains with

```
dpkg -L capnet-assist
```

In this case you'll see the `capnet-assist` does pretty much nothing else than providing the `captive-login` executable and some documentation for it. Knowing this you can then safely choose to remove the package `capnet-assist`, for example with

```
sudo apt-get remove capnet-assist
```

Now the package manager is aware of the change and will warn you if any other package depends on `capnet-assist`, in addition to not restoring the file next time `capnet-assist` is upgraded.